# GlassFish will not start because port 443 already in use by java

Tags: java, glassfish

GlassFish 3.0.1
RHEL 6.3

I changed the http-listener-2 port via the GlassFish Admin web page from 8181 to 443 and now GlassFish will not start because of a port conflict on port 443.

```
   0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=FelixStartLevel;|Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : Address already in use: 443=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@29ed3da1|#]
```

The process using port while GlassFish is starting (and only when GlassFish is starting) is GlassFish (or the JVM running GlassFish)

```
root> ls -l /proc/3242/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 17 17:19 /proc/3242/exe -> /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_34/bin/java
```

Quite a mess.  Now how do I get http-listener-2 back on to port 8181 and off port 443?
There must be a file (probably an XML file) which stores this information.

I can't use any asadmin commands because GlassFish is not up and running.  Isn't there an 'unset' command I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was that there existed 2 http-listeners on the same port (443). Removed the extra/duplicate http-listener from the GlassFish config file domain.xml and rebooted Glassfish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Asadmin is used to start the server, but asadmin is not dependent on the server started.
Check the documentation on how to use asadmin commands.
On changing the port no, check [this link](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport.aspx) out.

Comment: I did change the port in the domain.xml file but I get the error "JVM failed to start: com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherException: The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Command start-domain failed."

Comment: check your domain.xml file once again and make sure there are no errors in the file

Comment: I put back the original file -- JVM error still there.  And I have rebooted.

Comment: recommendation is to remove glassfish and install again if its urgent.

Comment: That may be what I end up doing.  Any suggestions on how to remove glassfish cleanly (other than brute force 'rm')?  I have never done an uninstall of GlassFish

Comment: The cause was that I had created 2 http-listeners on the same port. Removed the extra http-listener from the domain.xml file and rebooted and all is well.